# What is my mistake in proving that $A\subseteq B$ implies $B\subseteq A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

It's legitimate to use a tautology in any proof at any time right? Also whenever $P$ and $P$ $\implies$ $Q$ appears I Can announce $Q$, the reason being modes pones rule. So where is the mistake here?

**Proof that** $A \subseteq B \implies B \subseteq A$:

1. Assume $A \subseteq B$
2. Suppose $x \in A$
3. $A \subseteq B \implies (x \in A \implies x \in B)$ (*Definition of subset*)
4. $x \in A \implies x \in B$ (*Modus pones step 1 and 3*)
5. $x \in B$ (*Modus pones step 2 and 4*)
6. $x \in A \implies (x \in B \implies x \in A )$ (*tautology $q \implies (p \implies q)$*)
7. $x \in B \implies x \in A$ (*Modus pones step 2 and 6*)
8. $x \in B \implies x \in A \implies B \subseteq A$ (*Definition of subset*)
9. $B \subseteq A$ (*Modus pones step 7 and 8*)
10. $B \subseteq A \implies (A \subseteq B \implies B \subseteq A)$ (*tautology*)
11. $A \subseteq B \implies B \subseteq A$ (*Modus pones step 9 and 10*).

Comment: The definition of *subset* : $A \subseteq B$ is : $\forall x (x \in A \to x \in B)$. It is a predicate logic formula and not a priopositional one.

Comment: $B\subseteq A$ means $\forall x(x\in B\implies x\in A)$, but you have only obtained $\forall x(x\in A\implies(x\in B\implies x\in A))$.

Comment: The set A = {1, 2} is a  subset of B = {1, 2, 3}, the expressions A ⊆ B is true but is B ⊆ A? This is probably true only if A=B.

Comment: @NoChance thanks for the counter example, but i did point out that the proof is invalid. I wanted to know which step is wrong. frustratingly, none of the comments helped me.

Comment: As @LordSharktheUnknown points out,  the problem is that in step 8, your definition of subset uses the label $x$ to denote any element. In the previous lines you use the label $x$ to denote any element of $A$. You then conflate the two, essentially applying the subset definition only to those elements that are already in $A$ instead of to all possible elements, and thereby ignoring all elements in $B$ \ $A$.

Answer (score 7):

*Long comment*

The wrong proof is :

1) Assume : $A ⊆ B$

2) Suppose : $x ∈ A$

3) $\forall x \ (x∈A⟹x∈B)$ --- definition of *subset* [not used]

4) $x ∈ A ⟹ x∈B$ --- by [Universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) [not used]

5) $x∈B$ --- from 2) and 4) by *Modus pones* [not used]

6) $x∈A ⟹ (x∈B ⟹ x∈A)$ --- from tautology : $q⟹(p⟹q)$

7) $x∈B ⟹ x∈A$ --- by *Modus pones* from 2) and 6)

But we cannot apply the definition of *subset* to 7) in order to conclude with $B⊆A$ because we have not yet proved : $\forall x \ (x∈B ⟹ x∈A)$.

The "obvious" step is to apply [Universal generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization) to 7), but this move is invalid, because $x$ is *free* in assumption 2).

Intuitively, we have chosen an $x$ such that $x$ belongs to $A$ and we have derived, with this assumption, that $x∈B ⟹ x∈A$; but this does not mean that the formula that we have derived holds for $x$ whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of subset is incorrect, as it should be a universal quantified statement.

Certainly should we suppose that for any $x$ which satisfies $x\in A$, we may derive $x\in B\to x\in A$.   However, this is not the same as deriving $\forall x~(x\in B\to x\in A)$ , which is the actual definition for $B\subseteq A$.   All you can prove from this line of reasoning is that $A\cap B\subseteq A$.

$$\forall x~(x\in A\to(x\in B\to x\in A))\\\forall x~((x\in A\wedge x\in B)\to x\in A)\\\forall x~(x\in A\cap B\to x\in A)\\A\cap B\subseteq A$$